# Y scroll event listener useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My code underneath is a simple React component that sets a new state upon scrolling the page down. If the Y scroll exceeds a certain position it will set another state to true.

```
    const [ scrollPosition, setScrollPosition ] = useState(0);
    const [ confetti, setConfetti ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });
            check();

            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
            };
        },
        [ scrollPosition ]
    );
    const handleScroll = () => {
        const position = window.pageYOffset;
        setScrollPosition(position);
    };
    
    const check = () => {
        if (scrollPosition > 400) {
            setConfetti(true);
        }
        if (scrollPosition < 401) {
            setConfetti(false);
        }
    };
```

Everything is working smoothly as expected but I was just wondering if there is a less expensive way of doing this. Re-rendering the page every time Y scroll changes seems like a very inefficient way to run this code. I don't think throttling would be a good idea either as there might be a delay when a user scrolls down really fast.
Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to save the scroll position in the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
}, [scrollPosition]);
const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    if (position > 400) {
        setConfetti(true);
    }
    if (position < 401) {
        setConfetti(false);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In useEffect Hook , the value pass in last array depends the call the render method.
Whenever value in array change useEffect call and subsequently render method invoke.
Better you remove array value.

```
 useEffect(
    () => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });
        check();

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    },
    []
);
```